# Retrieve the .class attribute of a generic class

Tags: java, generics, ektorp

I am trying to extend the following class with constructor (from the Ektorp library):

```
public class CouchDbRepositorySupport<T extends CouchDbDocument> implements GenericRepository<T> {

...

protected CouchDbRepositorySupport(Class<T> type, CouchDbConnector db) {
...

}
```

Here's my implementation:

```
public class OrderRepository extends CouchDbRepositorySupport<Order<MenuItem>> {

    public OrderRepository(CouchDbConnector db) {
        super(Order<MenuItem>.class, db);
```

The problem is with the `Order<MenuItem>.class` part. The Java compiler tells me:

```
 Syntax error on token ">", void expected after this
```

I tried with `(Order<MenuItem>).class`, `Order.class` and `new Order<MenuItem>().getClass()` with no better luck.

What can I do to retrieve the .class attribute of a generic class?

Comment: There seems to be one of these a week.

Comment: @PaulBellora Possibly because any google query or SO query only returns questions about finding out the type of a generic object at runtime. This problem is somewhat different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your type to publish the inner type, you can get it this way:

```
public class CouchDbRepositorySupport<C, T extends CouchDbRepositorySupport<C>> implements GenericRepository<T> {
...

    protected CouchDbRepositorySupport(Class<C> type, CouchDbConnector db) {
        ...
    }

public class OrderRepository extends CouchDbRepositorySupport<MenuItem, Order<MenuItem>> {

    public OrderRepository(CouchDbConnector db) {
        super(MenuItem.class, db);
```

You have a few choices about how you declare the parent class; this is just one example.

Disclaimer: I did this by hand without an IDE, so there could be a few minor syntax issues with it, but the concept should work.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
Order.class
```

In Java, `Order<MenuItem>.class` and `Order.class` are *the same* class at runtime, the generic type information (the `<MenuItem>` type parameter) is lost at runtime because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) - a severe limitation of Java's generic type system.

Comment: The java compiler disagrees with that: `The constructor CouchDbRepositorySupport<Order<MenuItem>>(Class<Order>, CouchDbConnector) is undefined`

Comment: @jdreux you've said it yourself: the _compiler_. Generic types are checked during compilation, whereas the expression `Order<MenuItem>.class` is evaluated at runtime, and at runtime the type parameter `<MenuItem>` is _erased_ from the type information of the class, as if it never had existed

Comment: So there is not syntax for Order<MenuItem>.class because it's runtime equivalent does not exist?

Comment: @jdreux That's right. Read about it in this excellent [FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101), look at the questions "What is type erasure?" and "What is reification?". Quoting: "The JVM cannot tell the difference between a  List<String> and a  List<Date>"